# Remove certain items from control panel for some users

Tags: security, admin-pages

I have users that I would like only to see the My Settings section in the Control Panel and hide the Administration, Database, Reports, Localization, and Security items.  I've been looking in the Core database but don't see anything obvious that would allow me to remove read privileges to items like these.  Any way to do this?

Comment: The predefined Sitecore security roles can be used rather than setting the security at user level. [Unless you have a specific requirement to create a new combination of security]. For EX - Sitecore Client Authoring role will give minimum access to the control panel, not sure whether this will satisfy your requirement.

Comment: The user is a member of Sitecore Client AUthoring, but also of Designer, Author, Sitecore Client Publishing and Sitecore Client Designing.  These users need to be able to publish items edit them, etc., but shouldn't have access to some of these more administrative functions in the control panel.

Comment: Okay then as preferred in answer, creating a new role and set security for the control panel items in Core DB would be the best way..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am not reading into this right. But you can set denial permissions on the items on the menu items under the path `/sitecore/content/Applications/Control Panel/` in the core database.

I would prefer you create a user role and set the denial access to that role. Then adding users to the new role will be easier and cleaner to maintain.

Comment: There is no Control Panel listed in /sitecore/content/Applications in core.  Maybe that was only for an eariler version of Sitecore?  We are on 8.2.

Comment: I am looking at Sitecore 8.2 Update 4.  Can you search for item ID {AD6A5F44-088A-450E-9DBE-75DDADC94C57}.

Comment: Ugh, thank you, somehow it got dropped to the bottom of the list under Applications, rather than being in the alphabetically appropriate place!

Comment: Did this work for you?